# Perl MySQL utf8mb4 issue / possible bug

Tags: mysql, perl, utf8mb4

I am using Perl 5.20.2 and MySQL 5.5.57 on a Debian 8 machine. I recently discovered that MySQL's utf8 tables are limited to three-byte-characeters. As a consequence I can not store emojis.
So, I tried utfmb4 tables which are supposed to address the issue. I changed the table from utf8 to utf8mb4 from inside the mysql client:

```
ALTER DATABASE `mydb` CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` CHANGE `object` `object` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Storing data in mytable seems to work, at least I can see the expected emoji in phpMyAdmin. However, when reading from the table I receive a 4-character result with 3 unprintable charaters. The following program is supposed to print the same emoji twice:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.1;
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');

my $object = "\x{1F600}";
my $hd_db  = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:mydb:localhost', 'user', 'password');
$hd_db->do('SET NAMES utf8mb4');

# cleanup
my $delete = $hd_db->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable");
$delete->execute;

my $insert = $hd_db->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (object) VALUES ('" . $object . "')");
$insert->execute;
my $select = $hd_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$select->execute;
my $row    = $select->fetchrow_hashref;

say $object;
say $row->{'object'};
```

Expected output:

Actual output:

```
ð���
```

Seems like a bug to me. Any suggestion how to work around it?

**EDIT**: SELECTing the data from within the mysql client also shows the expected emoji

```
mysql> SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = utf8mb4;
mysql> SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = utf8mb4;
mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+--------+
| object |
+--------+
|       |
+--------+
```

Comment: You should really use placeholders.

Comment: Are you referring to the prepare statements? I usually do, but that did not seem relevant here

Comment: it was relevant enough that I took the time to point to it out ;-)

Comment: @simbabque, Please explain how using placeholders would resolve the issue with the utf8mb4 character set in the Perl client.

Comment: @Bill I never said it would. Just pointing out good style. We educate where we can. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You told MySQL to use UTF-8 for communication, but you also need to tell DBD::mysql to decode the data (or do it yourself).

You want

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:mydb:localhost', 'user', 'password', {
   mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1,
})
   or die($DBI::errstr);
```

which is equivalent to

```
my $dbh  = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:mydb:localhost', 'user', 'password')
   or die($DBI::errstr);

$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
   or die($dbh->errstr);

$dbh->{mysql_enable_utf8mb4} = 1;
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is the way to go for `DBI` versions >= 4.041_01. Debian 8 ships with 3.0.17. For that version decoding works when opting for `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1`, see [this post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mike_b/2016/12/dbdmysql-all-your-utf-8-bugs-are-belong-to-us.html)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to let MySQL treat everything as bytes and to do the encoding in your application.

```
use Encode qw(encode decode);

my $object = "\x{1F600}";
my $hd_db  = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:mydb:localhost', 'user', 'password');
$hd_db->do('SET NAMES latin1');

...

my $insert = $hd_db->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (object) VALUES ('" . 
    encode("UTF-8",$object) . "')"); # or equiv statement with placeholders
$insert->execute;

...

my $select = $hd_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$select->execute;
my $row    = $select->fetchrow_hashref;
say $object;
say decode("UTF-8",$row->{'object'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I would have to revisit more than 1k db queries in my application. And worse, they would have to be tested..

Answer (score 0):

`"\x{1F600}";` is "Unicode", not "utf8".  They are related, but they are *not* the same encoding.

You need `UTF-8` (as the non-mysql world calls it) and `utf8mb4` (as MySQL calls it).

is hex `F09F9880` (in utf8mb4); it is `ðŸ˜€` if you convert through `CHARACTER SET latin1` ("Mojobake")

Please run `SELECT HEX(object) ...` to see whether you get those 4 hex bytes or something else.  Then we will know whether to focus on the `INSERT` or the `SELECT`.

You say "actual output" -- but where is this?  A web page?  Is it configured for `UTF-8`?  Or something else?  If it is your commandline window, then make sure it is set for UTF-8.  In windows, that is done via `chcp 65001` .

You mentioned

```
mysql> SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = utf8mb4;
mysql> SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = utf8mb4;
```

That's only 2 of the 3 that need to be set.  Better to simply do

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

Comment: It was console output and it worked out of the box with both Ubuntu and W10/Putty 0.7. Win7/Putty 0.7 does not work out of the box, though I have not tried `chcp`ing

Comment: Compare `my.cnf`.  You may find different defaults.  What versions _of MySQL_?